# zend saving image from url

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am extracting all img urls from an array  and getting image urls from external sites...

how do i go about saving these images?

i tried using

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
 $upload->setDestination("img/");

 # Returns the file name for 'doc_path' named file element
 $name = $upload->getFileName('http://zendguru.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/ajax-form1.jpg');
```

but im getting nothing saved plus  its saying
Call to undefined method:- `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http::setOption()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you cannot do it using `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` as this works only with uploaded files. However, you could use `Zend_Http_Client` for this. For example:

```
    $c = new Zend_Http_Client();
    $c->setUri('http://zendguru.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/ajax-form1.jpg');
    $result = $c->request('GET');        
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($result->getBody());
    imagejpeg($img,'img/test.jpg');
    imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Zend for this. Plain PHP would do.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://zendguru.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/ajax-form1.jpg');
$fp = fopen('/img/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```